# How to get Store Product in debug mode of UWP app

Tags: c#, debugging, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am developing a UWP application.

In which I am trying to get store product details, by the code below

```
 StoreContext storeContext = StoreContext.GetDefault();
 StoreProductResult queryResult = await storeContext.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync();
```

Here `queryResult.Product` is always null.

I have associated my app Right click project > Store > Associate App with store > select app.

Kindly help me to get store product details , in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

That API, if I’m not mistaken, is only for retrieving In-app products for the current app.

I also tried once that API and it worked that way.